# Is it possible to use iframe with Flask to display a folium object?

Tags: python, html, flask, folium

I'm currently having a slight bug with my program when I attempt to save a folium object in Jupyter and then, upon moving it to Github's Codespaces, attempting to display the folium object itself in html via Flask.

I've tried using iframe in this way with the html file in a static folder, which doesn't give an error through flask (I get status code 200):
`<iframe id="serviceFrameSend" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='map.html') }}" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>` 
Unfortunately, the folium object itself doesn't generate in Flask, yet it does work when I download the folium or run it in Python. What am I doing wrong here?